# Can C# style object initialization be used in Java?

Tags: c#, java, initialization

In C# it's possible to write:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass()
{
    field1 = "hello",
    field2 = "world",
    field3 = new MyOtherClass()
    {
        etc....
    }
}
```

I can see that array initialization can be done in a similar way but can something similar to the above be done in Java too, and if so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That initialization syntax *is not present* in Java.

A similar approach is to use double brace initialization, where you create an anonymous inner sub class with an initializer block:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass() {{
  // in Java these would be more like this: setFieldX(value);
  field1 = "hello";
  field2 = "world";
  field3 = new MyOtherClass() ...
}};
```

Be aware though, that you're actually creating a *subclass*.

Another approach is to create a builder for `MyClass`, and have code like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClassBuilder().
  withField1("hello").
  withField2("world").
  withField3(new MyOtherClass()).
  build();
```

Comment: There is a useful Eclipse plugin for generating builders, though is not maintained any more https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: sooooo.... to get the easy instantiation syntax, I need to write a new Builder class?   For every type?  no thanks.

Comment: @Cheeso: you're right of course, it's really heavyweight to use this pattern for every class, and there's no need to do it really. It's a balance between author effort and consumer convenience, and I'm sure not every class would need to use it. [Joshua Bloch](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) gives some advice of when it might be useful.

Comment: wow java is so lacking compared to other languages, it's very surprising that it's used by so many people / organizations

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have the capability built in to instantiate an object using the shorter syntax. The C# compiler handles this and separates out the property setters in the IL. Until the Java langauge devs decide this is important, you will not be able to take this shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Just create constructors for initialization.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass()
{
    field1 = "hello",
    field2 = "world",
    field3 = new MyOtherClass()
    {
        etc....
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    public MyClass(String field1)
    {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this();
    }

    public MyClass(String field, Boolean isField1)
    {
        if (isField1)
            this( field );
        else
            this.field2 = field;

        this();
    }

    public MyClass(String field1, String field2)
    {
        this.field2 = field2;
        this(field1);
    }

    public MyClass(MyOtherClass field3)
    {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public MyClass(String field1, String field2, MyOtherClass field3)
    {
        this(field3);
        this(field1, field2);
    }

    private void initialize(){
        // Do any class bootstrapping here.
    }
}

// Then you have several ways to create an object instance, with initialization
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass( "Field 1 Value" );
MyClass myClass3 = new MyClass( "Field 1 Value", true );
MyClass myClass4 = new MyClass( "Field 2 Value", false );
MyClass myClass5 = new MyClass( "Field 1 Value", "Field 2 Value" );
MyClass myClass6 = new MyClass( "Field 1 Value", "Field 2 Value", new MyOtherClass() );
MyClass myClass7 = new MyClass( new MyOtherClass() );
```

Comment: Just huh? This is the correct answer but indicative of a fundamental wrongness.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do that, you just need to add the types before the `field1, field2 etc` other than that what you have should work. Its known as an anonymous class in Java.

Comment: This is not the same thing.