# Not able to initialize the properties of a class directly in Java during object creation

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the initialization of the object property directly but getting a compilation error.

**In C#, the below code works:**

```cs
new Employee() {
  Name = "John"
}
```

**In Java, can one please tell me the equivalent of the same, as the below piece of code throws compilation error:**

```java
new Employee() {
  Name = "John"
} // Throws error in Java

public class Employee {
  public string Name;
}
```

**I don't want to use the constructor to initialize the object, just for my understanding of the Java syntax. Please let me know if there is a way to initialize the object in Java as in C# like:**

```cs
new Employee() {
  Name = "John"
}
```

Comment: For learning the basics of Java, consider the official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: This is Java. You *have* to use the constructor, or a series of setters (if the class implements them).

Comment: Is using the constructor the only way to do this in Java?

Comment: See answer below/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can C# style object initialization be used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668156/can-c-sharp-style-object-initialization-be-used-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java equivalent is for the class to provide suitable constructors.

```java
new Employee("John");
```

That some other language does it some other way doesn't change that.

Alternatively, if the class is so implemented, you may write:

```java
new Employee().setName("John");
```

...though that seems needlessly clunky and also admits the existence of nameless Employees.

Setters like that would look like:

```java
Employee setXyz(String xyz) {
    this.xyz = xyz;
    return this;
}
```

...so you can chain them together.  But this approach is only better when there are comparatively many things that can optionally be set, and I would not recommend it for values that are required to be set, like the name of an Employee.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use constructor, you can do it by one of these way:

```
public class Employee {
    public String Name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Employee().Name = "John";
        // or
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.Name = "John";
        // or
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setName("John");

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way, although I strongly do not recommend it (as do some of the answers in the linked question): [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)

```
    static class Employee {
        String name;
    }

    @Test
    public void doubleBraceInit() {
        Employee john = new Employee() {{
            name = "John";
        }};

        assertEquals(john.name, "John");
    }
```

However: You are much better off using things like a) a good constructor, b) the builder pattern, or c) setters.